# "Seniority" vs. "rank"

Tags: word-choice, nouns

The following is a multiple choice question in a test paper:

> The chief of surgery became committee chairman by virtue of _____.
>   A. age
>   B. service
>   C. seniority
>   D. rank

I'm at a loss as to which one to choose and want to hear your opinions.

Comment: Are you allowed only one answer? Or could you say 'all of them'?

Comment: You know nothing about his age, service or seniority; all you know is his rank. Since that is all the information that is given, the *rank* of the chief of surgery is important. That's your answer. Reading English questions is sometimes more about the information given in the question than an actual informative answer. In future questions about homework, please let us know which *you* think it might be and why.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the usage actually there are three words that are cardinal and one that is a difference (relative measure):

*age* is cardinal: He is 50 years old the difference between ages is not.
*service* is cardinal: He has served for 25 years. 
*rank* is cardinal: He is a level 17 employee.

*seniority* however cannot be determined on it's own, it's by definition a relative measure.  You cannot be senior on your own it requires comparison with someone else — therefore the ONLY answer is `seniority`.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a definitively ambiguous question because the criteria for becoming committee chairman are not available. Any one of these could have been the criterion used by in his (I presume) becoming chairman. Seniority is also slightly ambiguous in my opinion as it means something like a position of some privileges arising from being older, holding a higher formal rank, or even having more years of service, all of which refer to the other options. Rank is usually a formal title in a hierarchical structure such as the military, but again I would ask  whether you know the ranks of the other members of the committee, or the other candidates for chairperson? Chief sounds "high" but we don't know whether it is the highest available for selection. If you have clues that the formal title/rank was an important criteria in the selection, I would choose rank.

Good luck in answering!

Comment: The decisive bit of information is provided in the question: *Chief of Surgery* is a rank.

Comment: @medica, my point is you don't know the selection criteria. Nepotism, or alumni preference, or age could be counting more than his rank. It also does not mention which committee he was elected to. Pedantic perhaps, and in the absence of other info I would go for rank, but it is still for me a very ambiguous question in the given context.

Comment: I think on first reading it is a challenging question, in that someone is likely to say *how the hell should I know?* But with a considered approach, the answer is right there.

Comment: @medica and wwkudu. The point of the question IS NOT to know why the Chief was given a position on the Committee, that is irrelevant to anyone learning English; the point of the question is to determine the readers comprehension of the question and their understanding that Chief is a rank (seniority could equally apply though). We become sort of programmed to find the right answer to a question, in this case it's not possible, but that isn't what the question is designed to do. I'd hate to do some of these tests, questions like that would annoy the hell out of me.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I also used to dislike this sort of question as I would get tied up in the ambiguities as I have done here :) The Chief of Surgery became chairman of the committee by virtue of age, as the Christmas Dance Committee wanted someone who looked a little more like Santa than the rest of the somewhat younger committee members. As I look for other examples, my pedanticism is becoming more apparent!

Answer (score 0):

With regard to grammar, they are all acceptable.

With regard to likely occurrence, **D** & **C** are likely.

The "best" option is missing:

**E. organizational ability**